# Transition metals and their ability to form coloured ions

Tags: transition-metals, crystal-field-theory

I understand that in solution. transition metals form coloured ions, but what about the transition metals in solid compounds that are coloured- is this also due to d-d transition?

can you give any examples of transition metals bonded to ligands in a solid state?

Comment: Essentially, ionic compounds are just a different kind of coordination complex in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit*: In this answer I've focused on solid solutions of transition metals, which are kind of half-way between pure transition metal solid compounds, and aqueous solutions of transition metal compounds (though more difficult to describe than either extreme...). I see now this is not necessarily what you were asking about, though it does fall under the question scope. Perhaps somebody else can supply the answer for the case of the pure transition metal solids.

Indeed, even in solid solutions, coordinated transition metals can be the source of colour.

The clearest examples are [gemstone sapphires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapphire). The main component (generally >98% by weight) of sapphires is just [aluminium oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide) ($\ce{Al2O3}$), also known as alumina. Though extremely widely available (to the tune of over 100 million metric tons produced per year worldwide), it is often used as a fine white powder or white/grey chunks. However if pure aluminium oxide is melted over 2100 °C and cooled slowly, it can form large completely colourless crystals. These can also be found commonly in nature, as the mineral [corundum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corundum).

(Even though these are colourless crystals, the industry already often refers to them as sapphire. See [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-x7XMPaWIE) on the industrial production of "sapphire glass").

However, small amounts of other elements (including, but not limited to, transition metals) can form stable [solid solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_solution) with aluminium oxide. Here, the impurity is the solute, and the aluminium oxide is the solvent. These impurities generally bind to the oxygen atoms, so it could be said that these impurities form coordination compounds (*oxo* complexes) dispersed inside the solid solvent. Note that formation of solid solutions is common in many situations, and not at all limited to aluminium oxide.

The exact characterisation of the coordination geometry for these impurities and the local crystal structure surrounding them is typically more complex relative to coordination compounds in solution. This is because, in most cases, the impurity atoms do not fit *perfectly* in the crystal lattice of aluminium oxide, and therefore the atomic structure suffers some local distortion. However, these disturbances are commonly limited to only a few tens or hundreds of atoms immediately surrounding the impurity.

The colour generated in these solid solutions can actually come from several sources. The simplest case is where the impurity (e.g. a transition metal) causes virtually no structural or electronic changes to the overall solid solvent, and colour is generated from electronic transitions in internal and largely undisturbed electronic orbitals (e.g., d-d transitions or f-f transitions). I believe this is relatively rare, except when using lanthanide impurities.

In other cases, the small amount of impurity doesn't strongly affect affect the atomic structure of the main component, but it donates electrons to (or pulls electrons from) the main component. This appears to be the case for most coloured sapphires.

Another possibility is that the impurities actually do cause havoc in the overall atomic structure of the crystal. Changing the crystal's atomic structure causes large changes in the [electronic band structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure). This can trigger absorption of light, even if the original components of the mixture were both colourless and no chemical reaction has taken place. This is generally only the case with addition of a large amount of impurities, though.

There's several other ways to generate colour in solid solutions, though a full list is outside the scope of this answer. For a soft overview of gem colouration, I recommend the site [Causes of Color](http://www.webexhibits.org/causesofcolor/6.html). A more technical analysis can be found at the [Gemology Project wiki](http://gemologyproject.com/wiki/index.php?title=Causes_of_color).